# How to extend AND mirror the screen?

Tags: windows-7, display, video, multiple-monitors

Currently I have one laptop with one HDMI port. I'm looking at getting a USB to VGA. Ultimately I would like to have 2 monitors. 1 that extends the laptop screen and 1 that mirrors the laptop screen. Is there any software to do this or can Windows 7 do this out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 detects both monitors, and gives you the option in the display settings to mirror or to extend. It is built into the OS. From what I have seen, I do not believe you can do both at once however. Just one or the other.

Comment: For fun, you can pick up free double or triple-screen wallpapers here http://www.digitalblasphemy.com/triscreen/triscreen1.shtml